# How to resolve the 'cannot get security labeling handle: No such file or directory' error?

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg, chroot

For a reason that completely escapes me, recently whenever I try to install a package or upgrade a package with APT or dpkg I get the error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive ... (--install):
 cannot get security labeling handle: No such file or directory
```

where `...`, of course, depends on the name of the Debian package archive (or `.deb`) being installed. If you're wondering whether it is something I've done to cause this well I don't think so, but I haven't run this Ubuntu 16.04.1 installation directly for quite some time. Rather I periodically chroot into this Ubuntu system from my Fedora system (if what I am saying is unclear, I mean I am running Fedora 25, but I chroot into this Ubuntu system) and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y` in order to keep this Ubuntu installation up-to-date.

Comment: I like to use strace when I run into errors such as these, especially when I don't know where to turn! :) Sometimes it is helpful and reveals what is missing.

Comment: How would that work in this context? Like I've used strace before when building AppImages and trying to figure out why they're not working but in that case there's something clear-cut to run it on but in this case what would I run strace on? dpkg? The Debian package?

Comment: I have run into this as well but do not have a solution. The reason this is happening is that SELinux is active in Fedora (in my case, CentOS), and when containers are run as privileged, they get `/sys/fs/selinux` in `rw` mode. Remounting in the container as `ro` will fix some of the issues, but what's really annoying for me is that I can install packages via the CLI but not via Ansible :-\

Answer (score 0):

Based on Naftuli Kay's answer the following command helped me solve this issue:

```
mount /sys/fs/selinux -o remount,ro
```